# Facebook, when I refresh it, shows, then removes/hides/moves articles/posts, is it ad settings? Similar?

Tags: facebook

A lot of the time when I move over to the tab containing Facebook and hit F5, I see a stream of articles, then before it has stopped rendering, some of the articles disappear, never to be seen or found by me again. A lot of times I can see things I'd like to read, interesting tidbits, never anything by my friends though, always non-friend content.

What/where in my settings controls this?

I have checked block settings, and I've only blocked a couple of friends' game invitations (Farmville anyone?) and a few app invitations.

What else can I check?

Comment: @pnuts I'll await a few more comments (or even an answer to the fact), but if it's off-topic I'd be happy to delete the answer myself (seriously).